# MATLAB Matrix having different types

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Entering `a=[70001999 0.086 0.003 0.1]` into MATLAB results in the following:

```
a =

1.0e+07 *

7.0002    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

I dont want it to be seen like that because my first column stores id numbers, and columns 2-4 store probabilities. What do I need to do to fix this??

Comment: i don't think you can use different displays for different items in your vector. if your vector stores different kinds of data, you could consider using a struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full precision is still there, it's just not displayed.  To display more type

```
format longg
```

For example, on my Matlab (I have `format longg` in my `startup.m` file)

```
>> a=[70001999 0.086 0.003 0.1]
a =
                  70001999                     0.086                     0.003                       0.1
```

If you want, you can also experiment some other display options.  For example, see if you like the display after each of the following.

```
format shortg; a
format shorteng; a
format longeng; a
```

Of course, use `help format` for more details.